# Mostrar ultimo registro ingresado, si aparece repetido

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hoy traigo una duda sobre ¿Cómo realizar una consulta?

Resulta que tengo una tabla llamada x, la cual cuenta con 3 o más registros (ID, MAC, FECHA_CREACION).

ahora deseo realizar un SELECT el cual me seleccione un rango de fechas ej.

```
SELECT
 ID, MAC, FECHA_CREACION
FROM x
WHERE
  FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN 'ayer (00-00-00)' and 'hoy (00-00-00)'
```

Resultado:

```html
<table border='0'>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>bcc810139fc0</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>ac202e43ef20</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>ac202e444e20</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>bcc810139fc0</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>ac202e43ef20</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>ac202e444e20</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>bcc810139fc0</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>bcc810139fc0</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>ac202e43ef20</td>
  <td>2018-10-24 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>bcc810139fc0</td>
  <td>2018-10-25 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>ac202e444e20</td>
  <td>2018-10-25 08:35:13</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Y todo funciona muy bien, pero ahora imaginemos que el rango de fechas tengo varias MAC iguales (caso posible, para la idea que desarrollo), entonces ahí va mi pregunta ¿Cómo hago para hacer una consulta la cuál si encuentra varias MAC iguales en ese rango de fechas, muestre la ultima ingresada (FECHA_CREACION)?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día compañero,

He realizado un pequeño ejercicio y me ha funcionado, espero te sirva:

```
SELECT ID, MAC, FECHA_CREACION
  FROM x A
 WHERE FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN 'ayer (00-00-00)' AND 'hoy (00-00-00)'
   AND FECHA_CREACION = (SELECT MAX(FECHA_CREACION)
                           FROM x B
                          WHERE A.FECHA_CREACION = B.FECHA_CREACION);
```

Acá lo que realicé fue crear una subconsulta de la misma tabla para comparar el valor de FECHA_CREACION y obtener el máximo o último.

Saludos cordiales,

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por el query realizado, pero no sé, a mi no me funciona, si, me muestra todas MAC dentro de ese rango de fechas, pero si una MAC está repetida con una linea diferente de tiempo (FECHA_CREACION), me sigue mostrando la mac y la mac repetida, debería mostrarme solo una (la ultima MAC registrada)

Comment: Correcto, si le deseas agregar que la MAC no se repita, también agrega otra subconsulta con el campo MAC, seleccionando cuando esta tenga la fecha máxima de creación y listo, intenta y me comentas

Comment: ¿Qué tal te fue @JuanD?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar Rownumber para contar los registros repetidos y solo mostrar los primeros que te devuelva:

```
WITH TableWRowNumber
AS
(
    SELECT A1.ID,A1.MAC,A1.FECHA_CREACION,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A1.MAC ORDER BY A1.MAC DESC) AS RowNumber FROM Macs A1
    WHERE FECHA_CREACION BETWEEN dateadd(d, (datediff(d, 0, GetDate() - 1)) , 0) and CONVERT(DateTime, GETDATE(),101)
       and FECHA_CREACION = ( 
    select MAX(A2.FECHA_CREACION) from MACs A2  
    WHERE A1.MAC = A2.MAC
    ) 
)

SELECT ID,MAC,FECHA_CREACION FROM TableWRowNumber WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1 ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DateTime, FECHA_CREACION,101)  DESC
```

Y al final solo seleccionas los que tengan el RowNumber = 1 y los ordenas de mayor a menor.

**`MySQL introdujo la ROW_NUMBER() función desde la versión 8.0. La ROW_NUMBER()es una función de ventana o función analítica que asigna un número secuencial a cada fila a la que se aplicó comenzando con uno.`**

> Ten en cuenta que si utilizas MySQL con una versión inferior a 8.0,
>   puede emular algunas funcionalidades de la ROW_NUMBER() función
>   utilizando otras técnicas.

Espero y te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: debes aclarar que row_number() como window function en mysql funciona solo en mysql 8 y del mismo modo las CTE también desde mysql 8

Comment: Listo compañero, muchas gracias por la observación, un saludo!.